# Generate a sequence of normally distributed numbers, V, that sum to a whole number, C and whose length is equal to C

Tags: normal-distribution

I am looking to solve the following problem in Python.

I need to generate a sequence of numbers, $V$, which satisfy the following parameters:

1. $V$ is normally distributed as assessed by Shapiro-Wilks test; or contains negligible variance ($\sigma \le 2$).
2. The length of $V$ is equal to a specified constant, $C$.
3. The sum of $V$ is equal to $C$.

So, where $C = 3$, $V$ might be $\{1.2, 0.8, 1.0\}$. In this case, $\sigma_V \approx 0.16$.

Below is some sample code which I generated that does NOT satisfy the parameters perfectly.

```
    def make_sequence(C: int):
    """Creates tuple, V, of size C, where length of V is equal to C and sum of V is equal to C
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    size: int
        Whole number integer or scalar
   

    Returns
    -------
    V: tuple
    """
    V = []
    for i in range(size - 1):
        bank = size
        choices = list(np.linspace(1, size, size*2))
        idx = random.choice(choices) # Python random module
        val = idx/bank
        V.append(val)
        bank -= 1
    V.append(size - sum(V))

    return(tuple(V))
```

This code works well for small values of $C$, but as the values of $C$ increase, the more non-normal the distribution of returned sequence, $V$, is.

Any thoughts? My initial idea after noticing the non-normality of $V$ was to set an arbitrary variance threshold and use a while loop to generate a sequence, but I am not confident this will work and am looking for other options.

Comment: Is the following equivalent to your question:  $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,c$ and the $X_i$ are all independent and identically distributed.  Do you want to generate a sequence $V=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_c)$ conditional on $\sum_{i=1}^c X_i=c$ ?  (If so, I don't see where the Shapiro-Wilks test has anything to do with that question.)

Comment: Take a look at the Conditional distributions section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution.

Comment: The three properties provided in the question are not enough to define a joint distribution on $\mathbf V$.

Comment: The answer (based on my comments above) is to take a random sample from a multivariate normal with mean $\bar{\mu}=\mathbf{1}_{c-1}$ and covariance matrix $\bar{\Sigma}=\sigma^2(\mathbf{I}_{c-1}-\mathbf{J}_{c-1}/c)$ where $\mathbf{1}_{c-1}$ is a vector with $c-1$ ones, $\mathbf{I}_{c-1}$ is the $(c-1)$-by-$(c-1)$ identity matrix, and $\mathbf{J}_{c-1}$ is a $(c-1)$-by-$(c-1)$ matrix of all ones. That gets you the conditional values of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{c-1}$ and $X_c$ is obtained from $c-\sum_{i=1}^{c-1} X_i$.  If you edit your question and it gets re-opened, I can put in the details.

Answer (score 3):

I have a suspicion that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), or perhaps a textbook assignment, because the constraints don't make a *lot* of sense to me. It's easy enough to provide a technical answer though.

For one, you don't want to be using any test for normality because these suffer from low power at low sample sizes, and become *over*powered at larger sample sizes (even the tiniest deviations from the theoretical normal will cause rejection). If you want your sample to be normally distributed, just sample from the normal distribution.

The great thing about the normal distribution is that mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ are completely independent, so you can tweak either to your heart's content. Here's a small function that will provide a solution with arbitrary $\sigma$:

```
import numpy
RNG = numpy.random.default_rng()

def make_sequence(C: int, sigma: float=1):
    V = RNG.normal(loc=0, scale=sigma, size=C)
    return(V + (C - numpy.sum(V))/C)
```

That's it. You'll still have to vectorize this in C, but as written this will return the strongest constraints requested with whatever $\sigma$ you specify.

You could also generate this via sequential sampling like you suggested, but either

- you'd still start from a known distribution, which just makes something like above more efficient.
- you'd have trouble determining how 'normal' the sample is for the reason I already mentioned. Implementations of the Shapiro-Wilk test usually limit the sample size they accept. [SciPy's version](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html) notes that "For N > 5000 the W test statistic is accurate, but the p-value may not be".

Finally, the second part of the condition 'normally distributed **or** $\sigma\le2$' sounds like it could very easily be gamed since the only other requirement for this problem is that $\bar V=1$, I might add an example later.